# Telegram file_id 400: ad Request: wrong file identifier

Tags: telegram-bot

I post to some of my channels a standard suggested animation. Next, the bot presented in this channel can repost the animation over a `file_id`.
But later in a while, it starts to fail with the error `400: ad Request: wrong file identifier`.
Once I post the same animation to the initial channel again it becomes available for bot again just with the same `file_id`

Who can I avoid the access lost?

Or is there a standard `ttl` for `file_id` to schedule an automotive refresh flow?